# Getting error while creating CI pipeline for gitlab with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am creating a ci pipeline in gitlab with aws using below code to work for ci. I have to execute only 3 stages for it and I have posted for code for coverage only as I am getting error init

```
coverage:
stage: test
tags:
    - aws-runner
only: 
    - Feature/CI            
image: python:3.7-slim
coverage: '/TOTAL\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+%)/'
script:
    - pip install coverage moto mock pytest
    - MIN_COVERAGE=85
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    - coverage run --omit 'utility/*' -m pytest tests/
    - coverage report -m
    - coverage html
    - COVERAGE=$(coverage report -m | grep -i "TOTAL" | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/%//')
    - if [ "$COVERAGE" -lt "$MIN_COVERAGE" ]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi
artifacts:
    expire_in: 7 days
    paths:
       - htmlcov/
```

---

This is the error for above code

```
 $ coverage run --omit 'utility/*' -m pytest tests/
 ============================= test session starts==============================
 platform linux -- Python 3.7.11, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 rootdir: /builds/test-backend 
 collected 0 items
 ============================ no tests ran in 0.00s =============================
 ERROR: file or directory not found: tests/
 Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
 Cleaning up file based variables
 00:02
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

As I am new to this, Any suggestion?
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the test directory exist or not and it should have .py files